# Break a long line into multiple lines on every occurrence of a pattern using sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file having single line (actually a very long line) as shown below:

{worda:wordB:[{"wordc","active":true},}{:wordb:"words","wordt""wordu""wordv","active":true} and so, on.

In this line, one pattern that is common is '"active":true'. I am trying to break this single line into multiple lines based upon this pattern.

Required output:
{worda:wordB:[{"wordc","active":true}
{:wordb:"words","wordt""wordu""wordv","active":true}

I tried sed and awk, however, either it is resulting into a 0 Kb file after processing or same file as the input file.

I have Windows environment and using GNU sed/awk for the same.

Please help.

Comment: format your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and add the sed/awk code you tried

Comment: Is it json? If so use a json parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/true}.*{/true}\n{/' file 
{worda:wordB:[{"wordc","active":true}
{:wordb:"words","wordt""wordu""wordv","active":true}
```

Brief explanation,
use `sed` to substitute `true}.*{` to `true}\n{`, where `.*` would be treated any characters, and `\n` would be the newline character